# 'accept' attribute in the input file type doesn't prevent the file to be stored in the 'State'

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, react-typescript

I have react app and I want to take file from the user and send it to the backend. The problem is when I set the `accept` attribute to accept only audio files it allows other files when you choose to show all the file in the file explorer.
Here is the code snippet for better understanding.

```
const FormCom: React.FC = () => {
  const [File, setFile] = useState<File | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(File?.name);
  }, [File]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container className="d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-center">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Form>
              <Form.Label htmlFor="THE_FILE">
                {File?.name ? File?.name : "Click here and choose the file"}
              </Form.Label>
              <Form.Control # KEEP IN MIND <Form.Control> IS AN INPUT ELEMENT. IT'S FORM REACT-BOOTSTRAP
                onChange={(x: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                  setFile(x.target.files?.[0])
                }
                type="file"
                name="THE_FILE"
                id="THE_FILE"
                accept="audio/*" 
              />
            </Form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormCom;
```

if you try it yourself you will see in the console that it's accept anything. Should I make a `Checker` function for that. Check if the file extension is correct then set it to the `State` or did I miss something in the `input` element.

Comment: when you inspect the element, does it have the `accept` attribute? either way, you should check the file type on the backend